# Is MQTT reliable over unreliable connection, such as a wifi-to-uart bridge?

Tags: mqtt

I'm applying MQTT on an IoT device. A WiFi-to-UART bridge is used to provide wireless network connection between a main controller MCU and the MQTT broker. To simplify the code on the MCU, the TCP connection is managed on the WiFi-to-UART bridge. However, since the WiFi-to-UART bridge does not support MQTT, the MQTT client runs on the MCU.

Now, the connection between the MCU and broker goes through UART, which is unreliable. Random error and lost may happen at a low but not zero chance. Is MQTT still reliable in this situation? If I set the MQTT QoS level to 2, does it still guarantee exactly one delivery of each message? Is the content still guaranteed to be right?

Answer (score 0):

[The MQTT protocol specifies](https://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v5.0/os/mqtt-v5.0-os.html#_QoS_2:_Exactly) the following regarding QOS level 2:

```
In the QoS 2 delivery protocol, the sender:

MUST assign an unused Packet Identifier when it has a new Application Message to publish [MQTT-4.3.3-1].
MUST send a PUBLISH packet containing this Packet Identifier with QoS 2 and DUP flag set to 0 [MQTT-4.3.3-2].
MUST treat the PUBLISH packet as “unacknowledged” until it has received the corresponding PUBREC packet from the receiver [MQTT-4.3.3-3]. Refer to section 4.4 for a discussion of unacknowledged messages.
MUST send a PUBREL packet when it receives a PUBREC packet from the receiver with a Reason Code value less than 0x80. This PUBREL packet MUST contain the same Packet Identifier as the original PUBLISH packet [MQTT-4.3.3-4].
MUST treat the PUBREL packet as “unacknowledged” until it has received the corresponding PUBCOMP packet from the receiver [MQTT-4.3.3-5].
MUST NOT re-send the PUBLISH once it has sent the corresponding PUBREL packet [MQTT-4.3.3-6].
MUST NOT apply Message expiry if a PUBLISH packet has been sent [MQTT-4.3.3-7].
```

And:

```
In the QoS 2 delivery protocol, the receiver:

MUST respond with a PUBREC containing the Packet Identifier from the incoming PUBLISH packet, having accepted ownership of the Application Message [MQTT-4.3.3-8].
If it has sent a PUBREC with a Reason Code of 0x80 or greater, the receiver MUST treat any subsequent PUBLISH packet that contains that Packet Identifier as being a new Application Message [MQTT-4.3.3-9].
Until it has received the corresponding PUBREL packet, the receiver MUST acknowledge any subsequent PUBLISH packet with the same Packet Identifier by sending a PUBREC. It MUST NOT cause duplicate messages to be delivered to any onward recipients in this case [MQTT-4.3.3-10].
MUST respond to a PUBREL packet by sending a PUBCOMP packet containing the same Packet Identifier as the PUBREL [MQTT-4.3.3-11].
After it has sent a PUBCOMP, the receiver MUST treat any subsequent PUBLISH packet that contains that Packet Identifier as being a new Application Message [MQTT-4.3.3-12].
MUST continue the QoS 2 acknowledgement sequence even if it has applied message expiry [MQTT-4.3.3-13].
```

And

```
When a Client reconnects with Clean Start set to 0 and a session is present, both the Client and Server MUST resend any unacknowledged PUBLISH packets (where QoS > 0) and PUBREL packets using their original Packet Identifiers. This is the only circumstance where a Client or Server is REQUIRED to resend messages. Clients and Servers MUST NOT resend messages at any other time [MQTT-4.4.0-1].
```

I can't tell if you are using a library or implementing this yourself or if you are receiver or sender from your question.

But if you are a sender as long as you haven't received a publish acknowledgement(PUBREC) and you manage to reconnect you should republish any messages that haven't been acknowledged.
And if you are a receiver you should keep receiving the message until you respond with a publish received(also PUBREC). If you have already received the message you should resend the publish received.

I am not sure how libraries handle QoS 2 when the connection drops in he middle of the exchange. It seems likely that they will try to reconnect but this is something you should probably check up on the the library documentation if you use one. This might also differ from library to library.

It also might be worth looking into the [retain feature for a publish](https://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v5.0/os/mqtt-v5.0-os.html#_Toc3901104).
This could ensure that the most recent message is retained on the server/broker in case you cant receive it at the moment due to connection issues.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm worrying potential bit errors in the header part of MQTT packets. Will it leads to an unexpecated behavior? For example, a bit error occurs at the byte indicating length of MQTT packet, making it unable to decode the packet. Another problem is the correctness of the packets if no extra checksum is provided in the packet.

Comment: As I understand it your reliability problems lie with your uart bus and your wifi module not with mqtt. The mqtt protocol assumes that all data being send from your wifi module is correct. Although the broker can detect malformed packages I wouldnt rely on it. Uart communication sends data in packets. These packets can contain a parity bit which can be used by the receiver to check the integrity of the packet. I would look into the documentation of your wifi module and your mcu to see if parity bits are being used. That would drastically improve the reliability of your uart communication.